# In R: conditionally change the first value of a group of values

Tags: r

I would like to change the first value of a sequence (of 1 or 2) to 0, however, this should not concern the first observation of a company's observations. I have shown below what I have and how I would actually want it to look, to try and make it more clear.
What we have:

```
companyID    status
    1           1
    1           2
    1           2
    1           2
    1           1
    1           1
    2           2
    2           2
    2           1
    2           1
    2           1
    2           2
    2           2
```

What I want:

```
companyID    status
    1           1
    1           0
    1           2
    1           2
    1           0
    1           1
    2           2
    2           2
    2           0
    2           1
    2           1
    2           0
    2           2
```

So whenever there is a change, I would like to change the value to 0 (apart from a change occurring because it is the observations of a new company).
Thank you in advance for your help!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `data.table` `rleid` :

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[, status := replace(status, 
            !duplicated(rleid(status)) & seq_len(.N) != 1, 0), companyID]
df

#    companyID status
# 1:         1      1
# 2:         1      0
# 3:         1      2
# 4:         1      2
# 5:         1      0
# 6:         1      1
# 7:         2      2
# 8:         2      2
# 9:         2      0
#10:         2      1
#11:         2      1
#12:         2      0
#13:         2      2
```

Answer (score 3):

Using library data.table

```
dt[, status := status * c(1,diff(status) == 0), by=companyID]
```

Or, using `library(dplyr)` if you prefer:

```
dt %>%
  group_by(companyID) %>%
  mutate(status = status * c(1, diff(status)==0))
```

The data:

```
dt = fread("
  companyID    status
    1           1
    1           2
    1           2
    1           2
    1           1
    1           1
    2           2
    2           2
    2           1
    2           1
    2           1
    2           2
    2           2
  ")
```

Comment: you could very slightly change it to get on one line `dt[, flag := status* c(1,diff(status) == 0), by=companyID]`